# Should we add a [homing] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

There are quite a few questions that are centered around homing or problems with homing. Currently we have no tag in place to identify such questions. You see that people choose the [y-axis](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/y-axis) or [axis](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/axis) instead (note that the [x-axis](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x-axis) also does not exist), to me this is too generic. A [homing](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homing) in combination with the relevant axis would define the issue perfectly.

Please share your thoughts on:

**Should we add the [homing](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homing) tag?**

This would require some (re-)tagging of existing questions and might require the need for tag [x-axis](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x-axis) as tags for Y and Z already exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes I do think we need such a tag ([homing](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homing)), homing is a specific action that should be identified as such. I've added the tag to a specific question on homing and will go through the questions to re-tag other questions. Also, the tag [x-axis](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x-axis) is also very beneficiary.

Comment: I too am in agreement on adding both the homing tag and x-axis tag.

Comment: Good move. There is no "Usage Guidance" for the tag though, it might be a good idea to add some...

Comment: @Greenonline done!